# Aerospike DB always starts in COLD mode

Tags: aerospike

It's stated [here](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/manage/aerospike/fast_restart.html) that Aerospike should try to start in warm mode, meaning reuse same memory region holding keys. Instead, every time the database is restarted all keys are loaded back from the SSD drive, which can take tens of minutes if not hours. What I see in the log is the following:

```
Oct 12 2015 03:24:11 GMT: INFO (config): (cfg.c::3234) Node id bb9e10daab0c902
Oct 12 2015 03:24:11 GMT: INFO (namespace): (namespace_cold.c::101) ns organic **beginning COLD start**
Oct 12 2015 03:24:11 GMT: INFO (drv_ssd): (drv_ssd.c::3607) opened device /dev/xvdb: usable size 322122547200, io-min-size 512
Oct 12 2015 03:24:11 GMT: INFO (drv_ssd): (drv_ssd.c::3681) shadow device /dev/xvdc is compatible with main device
Oct 12 2015 03:24:11 GMT: INFO (drv_ssd): (drv_ssd.c::1107) /dev/xvdb has 307200 wblocks of size 1048576
Oct 12 2015 03:24:11 GMT: INFO (drv_ssd): (drv_ssd.c::3141) device /dev/xvdb: reading device to load index
Oct 12 2015 03:24:11 GMT: INFO (drv_ssd): (drv_ssd.c::3146) In TID 104520: Using arena #150 for loading data for namespace "organic"
Oct 12 2015 03:24:13 GMT: INFO (drv_ssd): (drv_ssd.c::3942) {organic} loaded 962647 records, 0 subrecords, /dev/xvdb 0%
```

What could be the reason that Aerospike fails to perform fast restart?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using an enterprise release? Warm start is only supported by Aerospike's enterprise packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using community edition of the software. Warm start is not supported in it. It is available only in the enterprise edition.

Comment: Oops, I've missed that fact. Thanks!

Comment: Here's a full list of the features supported in the Enterprise Edition of Aerospike: http://www.aerospike.com/products/#products-enterprise